# Não consigo mostrar uma exceção quando coloco um valor que minha chave estrangeira não existe em JSON quando vou persistir

Tags: java, spring

Possuo uma classe Lancamento que dentro dela tenho 2 chaves estrangeiras que seria **pessoa_codigo e categoria_codigo**, consegui criar uma exceção quando informo um valor inexistente para alguma dessas chaves estrangeira! Neste caso, só estou conseguindo capturar o erro em uma coluna que seria: **categoria_codigo** já a coluna *pessoa_codigo** não consigo, pois me traz uma exceção que não sei como resolver.

Exemplo do meu JSON ao tentar persistir o objeto lancamento

```
   { "descricao": "Lanche",
    "dataVencimento": "2017-06-10",
    "dataPagamento": null,
    "valor": 10.20,
    "observacao": null,
    "tipoLancamento": "DESPESA",
    "categoria": {
        "codigo": 100
    },
    "pessoa": {
        "codigo": 10
        }
    }
```

Repare que no codigo da categoria eu coloquei o 100 que no caso não existe essa categoria no banco, mas consegui capturar minha exceção:

```
 {
    "msgUsuario": "Operação não permitida",
    "msgDesenvolvedor": "SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`algamoneyapi`.`lancamento`, CONSTRAINT `lancamento_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo_categoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`codigo`))"
}
```

Agora vou colocar por exemplo um valor no código na pessoa que não existe. e tenho esse Erro:

```
"timestamp": "2021-04-27T00:16:31.897+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"trace": "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141)\n\tat com.example.algamoney.service.LancamentoService.salva(LancamentoService.java:27)\n\tat com.example.algamoney.resource.LancamentoResource.criar(LancamentoResource.java:63)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle
  "message": "No value present",
    "path": "/lancamentos"
```

Minha classe Service

```
  @Service
public class LancamentoService {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LancamentoRepository lancamentoRepository;

    public Lancamento salva(Lancamento lancamento) {

        Optional<Pessoa> pessoaRecuperada = pessoaRepository.findById(lancamento.getPessoa().getCodigo());
        if (pessoaRecuperada == null || pessoaRecuperada.get().isAtivo() == false) {
            
            throw new PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException();
        }
        return lancamentoRepository.save(lancamento);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa noite. O problema é que tu está chamando o get do Optional sem testar se ele está vazio.
Você pode fazer desta forma:

```java
@Service
public class LancamentoService {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LancamentoRepository lancamentoRepository;

    public Lancamento salva(Lancamento lancamento) {

        Pessoa pessoaRecuperada = pessoaRepository
          .findById(lancamento.getPessoa().getCodigo())
          .orElseThrow(()-> new PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException());

        if (!pessoaRecuperada.isAtivo()) {
            throw new PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException();
        }

        return lancamentoRepository.save(lancamento);
    }
}
```

Outra forma seria:

```java
@Service
public class LancamentoService {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LancamentoRepository lancamentoRepository;

    public Lancamento salva(Lancamento lancamento) {

        Optional<Pessoa> pessoaRecuperada = pessoaRepository
          .findById(lancamento.getPessoa().getCodigo());

        if (pessoaRecuperada.isEmpty() || pessoaRecuperada.get().isAtivo() == false) {
            throw new PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException();
        }

        return lancamentoRepository.save(lancamento);
    }
}
```

O método Optional.isEmpty() está disponível a partir do Java 11.
Para o java 8 tem que usar a negativa do Optional.isPresent()

Comment: Show de bola deu certo!, capturei a mensagem de erro da exceção. Agora vou tentar ver como faço para capturar minha mensagem SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Dayson, tenta realizar desta forma, assim ele vai mandar a exceção pro controller e do controller vc pode tratar ou enviar o log ou enviar a exceção com o throw para quem requisitar ou simplesmente tratar no controller.

```
public Lancamento salva(Lancamento lancamento) throws PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException{

        Optional<Pessoa> pessoaRecuperada = pessoaRepository.findById(lancamento.getPessoa().getCodigo());
        if (pessoaRecuperada == null || pessoaRecuperada.get().isAtivo() == false) {
            
            throw new PessoaInexistenteOuInativaException();
        }
        return lancamentoRepository.save(lancamento);
    }
```

Comment: Valeu! consegui aqui obrigado..